# How to fix SSL error from Python apps (urllib) when behind HTTPS proxy?

Tags: ssl

Example of a failure:

```
***** Processing account GMail
Copying folder structure from Gmail to MappedIMAP
Establishing connection to imap.gmail.com:993.
WARNING: Error occured attempting to sync account GMail: [Errno 8] _ssl.c:490: E
OF occurred in violation of protocol
```

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Check out Greg's post here:
http://blog.grossmeier.net/2009/01/25/imapfilterofflineimapmsmtpmuttabook/

It's a really good summary and he has a sample .offlineimaprc for Gmail. His has a much different RepositoryRemote section

```
[Repository RemoteGmail]
type = IMAP
remotehost = imap.gmail.com
remoteuser = $user@gmail.com
remotepass = yep
ssl = yes
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a bug in the way either Gmail or whatever offlineimap uses (OpenSSL I assume?) implements SSL?

Comment: urllib =) see my answer

Answer (score 0):

https://bugs.edge.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python2.6/+bug/94130

This is a bug in python/urlib[2] there are some fixes in python2.6/2.7 but apps need to be ported as well.

*EDIT*

except that I'm wrong. It uses python ssl module, which uses OpenSSL.